# How to set document root to be the remote site root (not the local domain root) for PHP curl_exec() when using CURLOPT_URL

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to access a remote site document from my local site using PHP curl.  The remote document has some javascript stored in a subdirectory, and the browser returns 404 because curl_exec() is looking for <local_site_root>/<js_directory> rather than <remote_site_root>/<js_directory>.  I've scanned the web and PHP docs for examples, but found nothing.  Seems like a very simple use case, but what am I doing wrong/missing?  Thanks, N.

This is the PHP on my local site...

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.remotesite.com/curltest.html";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This is the curltest.html document on the remote site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>curltest</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    trying to execute a js file in a sub Directory
    <script src="/curltest/sub.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the browser reports

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /localhost/curltest/sub.js

How do I get curl_exec to prefix the remote server docroot to the filename, rather than the local docroot?  It knows what it is, after all, since I told it with curl_setopt().

For the avoidance of doubt, the remote server finds the file correctly when I browse to remotesite/curltest.html directly.

Thanks for your help,

N.

Comment: This has nothing to do with cURL. cURL just requests the server and returns what the server responds with as-is. It doesn't parse and modify the content. If you want to change the URL's in the HTML you get, you need to do that after.

Comment: You seemingly want to write a web scrapper for off-line browsing. That's anything but a simple use case. Software that does so (such as [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/)) has lots of work behind.